# number of quotient sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let c be the equivalence relation

$$ \{ (4,0),(1,7),(2,4),(8,7),(6,3),(7,6)\} $$

on [0,9].

How many elements exist of [0,9]/c?

So I have 3 equivalence classes: 
$$ [2]=[4]=[0]$$
$$[1]=[7]=[6]=[3]$$
$$[8]=[7]=[6]$$

Unfortunately the correct answer is 4 elements and not 3. 
Do I understand something wrong here?

I appreciate each hint.

Comment: Maybe, I just don't understand your notation, but according to what you've just given, $4 \sim 0$ but $0 \nsim 4$, so this is not an equivalence relation.

Comment: The relation $c$ is neither reflexive, symmetric nor transitive. Are you thinking of the least equivalence relation containing $c$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$8$ should be part of the second class you show, as it is matched with $7$.  Then you have a class for each of $5$ and $9$, making four.

Answer (score 1):

Your equivalence classes should be exhaustive, i.e. every element should be in some equivalence class. And for example you haven't listed $5$. Thus, since $5$ is shown to be not related to anything, it is its own equivalence class (if a certain relation is an equivalence relation, every element is related to itself).

Also notice that in your answer $7$ is both in your second equivalence class as well as your third equivalence class. And that cannot be, since equivalence classes are disjoint. Do you see how to fix it?